# Greek characters are not displayed correctly in QGIS on Windows 8

Tags: qgis, shapefile, windows-8, encode

I am working on a laptop with two operation systems. One Windows 8 and one with Ubuntu 12. In both systems I have installed QGIS and in Windows I also have the FME 2014. I am trying to load a shapefile which has attributes in Greek characters but while everything is displayed correctly in my Ubuntu installation, I get "strange" characters in my Windows system (both in FME and QGIS). The encoding of the shapefile is in UTF-8 and I have tested it in another PC with Windows 7 and it was displayed correctly.

I tried to save the shapefile and loading it again but this doesn't fix the problem. I am convinced that this must be related with my Windows installation but I don't know what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that FME and qGIS are too different stories.
FME has an own issue with greek characters in shape files generated by ArcGIS ("Thank you for contacting Safe Software's support group.  Unfortunately this is a known issue for Shape files created with ArcGIS.")

Regarding qGIS the solution was simple enough. I changed the encoding of the loaded layer by right clicking on it and going to Properties ->General.
I set the encoding to: "windows-1253".

Answer (score 1):

Dkar did you check your Windows encoding ? (CMD>>chcp). You wrote that on Win7 its ok, check this command on booth systems and compare results.